# Hard Drive filling up quickly and constantly

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware, filesystems, search

We have a few programs that do a lot of stuff with file management and logs.  I think one of the programs is filling up the hard drive, but I have no idea which one or how exactly its happening.  Is there any way to search a drive, like C: for files > 1.0GB?  Or some means to organize all files on the hard drive by size.

Whatever the means I really don't care, I just need to find out where this file or directory is that is so hugemongous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 options I've used:
Open computer, select C:, in the top right you have a search box, put in *.* and click on Size under search filter, select Gigantic.

Or install [Space Sniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You might try a third party application like [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) which will index your harddrive and give you a nice graphical representation of where all the space is allocated.

Comment: nice tool, I like how everything is broken down into trees.  Makes it easy to narrow down issues like this.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Yea, I use it on all my file servers to find people's "hidden" iTunes folders. =P

Answer (score 2):

Heres a brief walk-through using Powershell -- http://www.christiano.ch/wordpress/2009/08/11/powershell-how-to-find-large-files/

To quote the article, something like this will find files greater than 100MB:

```
gci c:\ -rec -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | where {$_.Length -gt 100mb}
```